# How do I get blender to work on OSX El Capitan?

Tags: osx

Ok, so recently I updated to El Capitan, and I have had so much trouble figuring out how to move the camera around and just do basic trackpad movements like I used to be able to do. I have followed this tutorial since I started using blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCgt4ODsWYQ
and it has worked until now. Does anyone know how to fix this?